# Issue with PDO statement - general error

Tags: php, pdo

Hey guys I have the following:

```
$newStatus = "Non-Active - Driver Chose Non-Compliance";

    $sql = "SELECT username,ATF FROM members WHERE username = 'test'";
    $getcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($sql);
    $getcsvuser->execute();
    while($row = $getcsvuser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $memusername = $row['username'];
        $memATF = $row['ATF'];
        if ($memATF != 0 || $memATF != "0")
        {
        $tsql = "SELECT username,status,memberview ,statuschangedate FROM csvdata WHERE memberview =:user";
        $tgetcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($tsql);
        $tgetcsvuser->execute(array(':user' => $memusername));
        while($trow = $tgetcsvuser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $csvstatus = $trow['status'];
            $csvusername = $trow['username'];
            $csvdate = $trow['statuschangedate'];
            echo $csvstatus;
            if($csvstatus == "Open" || $csvstatus == "Enrolled - Policyholder Follow-Up Required" || $csvstatus == "Enrolled - Employee Follow-Up Required" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active - Insurance Cancelled" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active, Unable to Monitor - Incidental Business use Exclusion" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active - Employee Not Covered Under Listed Policy" || $csvstatus == "Non-Active - PolicyHolder Cancelled Additional Interest")
            {
                try {
                $newsql = "update csvdata set status =:newstatus where statuschangedate < NOW() - INTERVAL :atf DAY AND username =:mem";
                $newgetcsvuser = $DBH->prepare($newsql);
                $newgetcsvuser->execute(array(':newstatus' => $newStatus, ':atf' => $memATF, ':mem' => $csvusername));
                while($qrow = $newgetcsvuser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    echo "working";
                }
                 } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
            }

        }
        }

    }
```

Everything works great except once I get into the try {}..I get an error saying SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error.

What I am trying to do is have the statement check the statuschangedate, which is in a data type of yy-mm-dd.  To see if it is past the due of their members atf date they put down, if so change and update the status of that employee. Issue is this is not working and I am having trouble figuring out why.

I could use a hand and would much appreciate it!

David

Comment: Im not sure PDO will be happy with you nesting and reusing statements without closing the previous. You might have better luck using multiple connection handles for this sort of arrangement.

Comment: I guess issue is with  while($qrow = $newgetcsvuser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  i.e. after update execute statement , you are trying to process result considering array value return which may not be a case ..   Check  var_dump on $newgetcsvuser->execute(array(':newstatus' => $newStatus, ':atf' => $memATF, ':mem' => $csvusername));    this will tell if return value is array

Comment: @Shridhar your correct when I remove it, it goes away but it does not execute....I'll see what happens with that.

Comment: @Shridhar it returns bool(true)  abnch of times.  But there is no executing

Comment: Not sure why you are using while loop there, you can simply use if statement like  $result = statement execution ; if($rsult){ echo success } else { echo  fail}

Comment: @Shridhar I was only doing it to see if it was working.  But it is not working because when I look in DB it does not show the status has been updated.

Comment: @Shridhar it fails everytime

Comment: if update statement not working means, generally, it is not well formed sql statement. you may need to see sql

Comment: @shridhar is there anything wrong with this in your eyes? `$newsql = "update csvdata set status =:newstatus where statuschangedate < NOW() - INTERVAL :atf DAY AND username =:mem";`

Comment: Lets say new status is open and the statuschangedate is the column inside the database where the date is and than the :atf is 1 and :mem is joe

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24539/discussion-between-shridhar-and-david-biga)